# Unable to insert or retrieved data to MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I try to insert and pull some data from MongoDB.
The connection was setup correctly follow there instruction on mongodb.com

```
try:
    client = MongoClient(
        'mongodb+srv://user:pw!@cluster0-nghj0.gcp.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true',
        ssl=True)
    print("connected")
except:
    print('failed')
```

I manually create a Database: messager.messager and put some json file in it

when I try to use `collection.find()` or `collection.insert_one(...)`

```
db = client.messager
collection = db.messager

for i in collection.find():
    print(i)
```

It returns Timeout error:

```
File "/Users/anhnguyen/Documents/GitHub/GoogleCloud_Flask/comming soon/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymongo/cursor.py", line 1225, in next
    if len(self.__data) or self._refresh():
  File "/Users/anhnguyen/Documents/GitHub/GoogleCloud_Flask/comming soon/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymongo/cursor.py", line 1117, in _refresh
    self.__session = self.__collection.database.client._ensure_session()
  File "/Users/anhnguyen/Documents/GitHub/GoogleCloud_Flask/comming soon/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1598, in _ensure_session
    return self.__start_session(True, causal_consistency=False)
  File "/Users/anhnguyen/Documents/GitHub/GoogleCloud_Flask/comming soon/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1551, in __start_session
    server_session = self._get_server_session()
  File "/Users/anhnguyen/Documents/GitHub/GoogleCloud_Flask/comming soon/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1584, in _get_server_session
    return self._topology.get_server_session()
  File "/Users/anhnguyen/Documents/GitHub/GoogleCloud_Flask/comming soon/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymongo/topology.py", line 434, in get_server_session
    None)
  File "/Users/anhnguyen/Documents/GitHub/GoogleCloud_Flask/comming soon/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymongo/topology.py", line 200, in _select_servers_loop
    self._error_message(selector))
pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: connection closed,connection closed,connection closed
```

Where did it goes wrong ?
Here is my Mongodb.com setup:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [pymongo documentation for errors](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/errors.html) you have the following issue.

**exception pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError(message='', errors=None)**

**Thrown when no MongoDB server is available for an operation**

**If there is no suitable server for an operation PyMongo tries for serverSelectionTimeoutMS (default 30 seconds) to find one, then throws this exception. For example, it is thrown after attempting an operation when PyMongo cannot connect to any server, or if you attempt an insert into a replica set that has no primary and does not elect one within the timeout window, or if you attempt to query with a Read Preference that the replica set cannot satisfy.**

You have to check whether your network has good connectivity to the network where your MongoDB server resides.
There might be a case, where the Primary Node of the Replica Set becomes unresponsive. In such cases you need to restart your cluster(if you have the access permissions).

Also, create the connections as follows:

```
mongo_conn = MongoClient('mongodb+srv://cluster0-nghj0.gcp.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true', username=your_username, password=pwd, authSource='admin', authMechanism='SCRAM-SHA-1')
```

above is the best practice to follow. `mongodb+srv` urls do not need the `ssl=True` mention.

Comment: ```Collection(Database(MongoClient(host=['cluster0-shard-00-01-nghj0.gcp.mongodb.net:27017', 'cluster0-shard-00-02-nghj0.gcp.mongodb.net:27017', 'cluster0-shard-00-00-nghj0.gcp.mongodb.net:27017'], document_class=dict, tz_aware=False, connect=True, authsource='admin', replicaset='Cluster0-shard-0', ssl=True, retrywrites=True), 'messager'), 'messager')```
I have it connect accordingly when i print out collection.
The connect request also show up in mongodb.com chart.

Comment: `client` variable in your code, which is the MongoClient instance, has a`list_databases` method defined on it. If `client.list_databases()` returns a list of database names present on the server, your connection is fine, else you need to ask the Database Administrators to troubleshoot the Nodes.

Comment: Is your cluster a MongoDB Atlas deployment? If Yes, then you need to whitelist your IP address in the Security tab on the homepage. [Whitelisting IP MongoDB Atlas](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwig_ojurIriAhVLpo8KHXHrAnsQFjABegQICxAK&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DleNNivaQbDY&usg=AOvVaw2AdxTEkO67fnmHQAAjNweh) follow this link for any help

Comment: Thank you, after adding my IP to the white list, I have successfully connected to Mongodb